# How to list files in media library folders using shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

Is it possible to show file list in folders in media library, thru a shortcode?. My files are hosted in Google cloud storage, but all are included in media library,. 
Are there any plugin to list the files in a folders by taking in a shortcode argument as the folder name.?.

Comment: wp has tons of media library plugins https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-library-assistant/

Comment: I have tried those plugins, they don't list files by taking in folder names.